Source for satellite images without geometric correction
I need satellite images for a university project and they must not have passed through geometric correction. So far the images I have found are already geometrically corrected in some form. Is there a source of satellite images that have not been corrected ?

Organizations that provide Satellite Imagery (USGS / Earth Explorer) are required by law to give out data that has been corrected / refined.

Most users have no application for uncorrected images - they will not line up with adjacent images in space or time. You might find a few examples here or there in a tutorial on georectification. I was surprised how hard it was to find an example, though.
I was not able to find a downloadable collection of uncorrected Landsat images. The Sentinel 2 Products description explicitly states that unrectified imagery is not available for download.
An example of an uncorrected aerial image archive is found at the USGS EROS archive.
USGS EROS Archive - Aerial Photography - Aerial Photo Single Frames
The closest example I could find that meets your requirements is this set of PlanetScope sample data. You'll want the Basic Analytic Radiance (TOAR) product.
